# $inc + addToSet and populate - NodeJS - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to inc variable in a ref object:

**userModel**

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    pseudo : { type : String },
    fullname : { type : String },
    password : { type : String },
    email : { type : String },
    //tags : { type : Array },
    tags : [
        {
            objectId : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'tag'},
            completed : { type : Boolean, default : false }
        }
    ],
    dateCreation : { type : Date, default : Date.now }
});
```

**tagModel**

```
var tagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name : { type : String },
  alias : { type : String },
  description : { type : String },
  countMembers : { type : Number, default : 0 },
  dateCreation : { type : Date, default : Date.now }
});
```

**I have tried:**

```
userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
req.session.passport.user._id, 
{ $inc: { "tags.objectId.countMembers": 1 }, $addToSet: {"tags": { objectId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(publicTag._id.toString()) }}},
{ upsert: true },
function(err, model) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
});
```

**and**

```
userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
req.session.passport.user._id, 
{ $addToSet: {"tags": { objectId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(publicTag._id.toString()) }}},
{ $inc: { "tags.objectId.countMembers": 1 }, upsert: true },
function(err, model) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
});
```

I get an error 'can not use the part..' :(

Maybe I have to use populate ? I don't know..

And if a person have a good website/link to understand extra option in query mongoose..

Each time I'm looking for the problem during 3 hours just to use 1 query when I mixed several options like **$inc** and **upsert** for example.

Thanks,

Comment: Populate is not "join" magic. MongoDB acts on single collections at a time. So unless the data is actually embedded you cannot do this without solely acting on the source collection. Not the parent.